# MARS IDE simulator

Tags: windows, installation, jar, mips

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdplc.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZFes.png)

When I try to download the MARS from the Missouri State website: https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/download.htm it opens up in eclipse and dones't want to open up the software. I have jdk downloaded [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z35Qv.png). I just got this Lenovo laptop so the settings are different to me. Please let me know what I should do. Thanks!

I tried opening it up using JDK and It just closes out. I'm not sure if I'm even using the right JDK application. Here is a screenshot of what I tried opeing it on: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV8eb.png)

Comment: Here's how I run it using windows command line (`Command Prompt` / `cmd.exe`): `java -jar C:\...\...\MARS4_5.jar`, where the `...` is your path to the `.jar` file.

Comment: Don't open the .jar file in a code editor--[double-click it to run it as a program](https://youtu.be/u5Foo6mmW0I?feature=shared&t=216).

Comment: @ErikEidt WOW THANK YOU SO MUCH, IT WORKED! do you know how to get it to open normally? like have it on the desktop and just open it?

Comment: Double clicking the .jar should work (I don't use that b/c I don't keep the .jar file on my desktop), so if it doesn't it might be windows file associations are not properly set to run java??  Sounds like the windows file associations for .jar are set to Eclipse, when I would think they should be set to java.

Comment: But it is easy to make a .bat file that contains the line I mentioned.. And you can double click on that.